Weird error behavior when implementing Euler's method for solving ODEs in Python
I am solving this particular ODE:
$$
\begin{cases}
u'(t)=-2\,tu^2/20, \quad  t \in [0,\sqrt{20}]\\
u(0) = 1
\end{cases}
$$
which the analytical solution is given:
$$
  u(t) = \frac{1}{1 + t^2/20}.
$$
Furthermore, I am evaluating the expression at different step sizes, as such:
$$n=2^k, h=\sqrt{20}/2^k, 0 \le k \le 9$$
I then calculate the value for $u(t=\sqrt{20})$ and compare it to the value of the approximate function given by the Euler method at the same point. I expected the error to be halved at each iteration. However, surprisingly, the error at $n=2$ is in the order of $1\cdot10^{-16}$. After that, the error behaves as expected. My results are shown in the table below:



n
u Euler
u Exact
Error
Ratio




1
1.0
0.5
0.5
-


2
0.4999999999999999
0.5
1.1102230246251565e-16
4503599627370496.0


4
0.5083560943603516
0.5
0.008356094360351562
1.328638687821671e-14


8
0.5045486124686074
0.5
0.0045486124686073826
1.83706447142328


16
0.5022642864188357
0.5
0.0022642864188356926
2.0088503074387125


32
0.5011213922644928
0.5
0.0011213922644928154
2.0191742805179653


64
0.5005571541057451
0.5
0.0005571541057450835
2.012714710220388


128
0.5002775936902161
0.5
0.0002775936902160714
2.0070849064019067


256
0.5001385392778465
0.5
0.00013853927784646114
2.0037183283409346


512
0.5000692038113869
0.5
6.920381138686427e-05
2.0019024251713047



Why is this happening at $n=2$?

Use an Euler with adaptative size.

This is quite normal, absent the coincidence that the error is this small in the largest step sizes.
The linear reduction of the error according to the order 1 of the method does only occur where the first term in the error expansion in powers of $h$ dominates all the other terms. For large $h$ these other terms however will be larger. For very small $h$ the accumulation of the small step updates will fall below the capabilities of the number format (summation tricks effectively change the number format for a higher precision). This gives a typical V-shape in a loglog plot of error vs. step size, with a wavy end at large step sizes.
See

a loglog plot for a second-order method: Numerical Analysis: Heun's method,
the same for a 4th order method with wavy end: Truncation error with growing step size
contemplation about the different error contributions: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/37425/how-error-scales-with-numerical-precision-in-molecular-dynamics,


Thank you for your answer. However, I have found what I believe to be the cause in this case. For some coincidence of numbers, the Euler method gives out the exact solution for $n=2$ and the Python output is not exact due to floating point rounding errors.

This looks correct. The first floating-point error is from the square root in the step size, thus unavoidable.

This seems to be only a coincidence of numbers since Euler's method gives out the exact solution for $n=2$. The Python output is only not exact due to floating point rounding errors
$$
k=1, \quad n=2^{k}=2, \quad h=\frac{\sqrt{20}}{2^{k}}=\frac{\sqrt{20}}{2}, \quad T=\sqrt{20}\\
t_k = \frac{k}{n}(T-t_0)+t_0\\
t_0 = 0, \quad t_1 = \frac{\sqrt{20}}{2}, \quad t_2 = \sqrt{20}\\
u'(t_k) = \frac{-2t_ku(t_k)^2}{20}, \quad u(t_0 = 0) = 1\\
u(t_{k+1})=u(t_k)+hu'(t_k)\\
u(t_1)=u(t_0)+h\frac{-2t_0u(t_0)^2}{20}=1+\frac{\sqrt{20}}{2}\frac{-2\cdot 0\cdot 1^2}{20}=1\\
u(t_2)=u(t_1)+h\frac{-2t_1u(t_1)^2}{20}=1+\frac{\sqrt{20}}{2}\frac{-2\cdot \frac{\sqrt{20}}{2}\cdot 1^2}{20}=1-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}\\
$$
And, since the exact solution is known and substituting $t_2 = \sqrt{20}$:
$$
u(t) = \frac{1}{1+t^2/20}\\
u(\sqrt{20}) = \frac{1}{1+\frac{\sqrt{20}^2}{20}} = \frac{1}{1+1} = \frac{1}{2}\\
$$
